# Wrong path for Qt mkspecs when generating Makefile for VTK under Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake, vtk

My current task is to set up a working environment for an application using (static) Qt and VTK, under Windows 10.

I successfully installed the Qt 5.11.1 static and now want to build VTK. Any version of VTK does, as long as it is compatible to Qt 5.11.1, and the Qt Modules (VTK_Group_Qt) have to be build. For my version, I decided on VTK 8.1.1, but as said, any version would do.

I used the CMake GUI to configure VTK, using MinGW Makefiles (I use a MinGW64), which worked. Then I wanted to proceed generating the Makefile, having turned on VTK_Group_Qt. The paths and version of Qt were already correctly recognized:

> Qt5Core_DIR       C:/build_environment/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt5Core
>
> Qt5Gui_DIR          C:/build_environment/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui
>
> Qt5Widgets_DIR C:/build_environment/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets
>
> Qt5_DIR               C:/build_environment/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt5

Made sure that all of those exist. After that, I hit Generate and got the following error:

> The imported target "Qt5::Core" references the file
>
> "C:/build_environment/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1/qtbase/.../qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1/qtbase//mkspecs/win32-g++"
>
> but this file does not exist. Possible reasons include:
>
> * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
>
> * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
>
> * The installation package was faulty and contained
>
> "C:/build_environment/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/qt5CoreConfigExtras.cmake"
>
> but not all the files it references

Now, we see that it goes one folder upwards from qtbase and then into the very folder it currently is in, which of course is not a legitimate path. That is, for some reason it tries to go up and then down again, but not with the right amount of folders.

I could try to move the contents of my Qt installation so that the path would be legitimate, but I'd consider that to be pretty much of a smell. Fiddling around in a folder structure that should be correct is not what I understand to be a good solution. I'd rather be willed to change one of the .cmake files of Qt, but that would also be more of a makeshift approach than a real solution as far as I am concerned.

One thing I tried so far was to look at all the CMake variables (checking Advanced in the CMake GUI) in order to see if everything appear to be in order, and especially to see if that faulty path to mkspecs is to be found somewhere there. Found nothing of particular interest.

Does anybody have an idea what went wrong? Tell me if additional information is required. In parallel, I will try to build other versions of VTK, but I'm not too confident that this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution which I want to present here, but I consider it a makeshift approach rather than an actual solution, and I hope to see a better answer.

I went to `qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/` and changed the file `Qt5CoreConfigExtrasMkspecDir.cmake` (after making a copy).

The original file contains a single line

```
set(_qt5_corelib_extra_includes "${_qt5Core_install_prefix}/.../qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1/qtbase//mkspecs/win32-g++")
```

which leads to the faulty path. I changed it to

```
set(_qt5_corelib_extra_includes "${_qt5Core_install_prefix}/mkspecs/win32-g++")
```

And it now works fine. Still, I don't feel good about having to change a file of Qt, since I consider the answer the question "Is this famous library at fault?" to be "Most likely I used it wrong."

A possible explanation would be that I used the wrong install prefix when configuring Qt, but shouldn't I be allowed to put any valid writeable path in there? Plus, the prefix is still in the cmake file and thus has some validity.

While this is an answer since it fixed the problem, I'd really like to read comments about what could have originally went wrong.

Comment: It's clear as a day that it's a typo, I think. Report it as a bug. Qt may even create the full install prefix if it doesn't exist, I don't recall though.

Comment: @KubaOber Listened to your advice and reported it. If anybody is interested in the outcome, my request is found under https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-70189